# Link tipo Ancora dentro de um iFrame

Tags: css, html5, iframe

Fala pessoal, tudo certo ?

Desenvolvo para uma loja virtual! E ná pagina dos produtos as descrições estão sendo criada por `iframe`! ( sim , infelizmente não estou conseguindo mudar isso)

Ou seja temos um `domínio` só pra criar os anúncios (Anúncios seriam páginas `html` qualquer) e embarcar eles via `iframe` no domínio que está hospedado a loja!

Bem ciente desse cenário, temos um uns link dentro dentro desse `iframe` com `ancoras` para dentro dele mesmo, porém não funciona! Fora do `iframe` ( Dentro do dominio onde são gerado os anuncios , funciona certinho) Ja pequisei de diversas formas, ja fiz por linha normal exemplo:

```
<li><a href="#ancora">Link 1</a></li>
```

E dentro do conteudo que é gerado pelo iframe tem o

```
<a name="ancora"></a>
```

Já testei com target também e não funcionou
Já tentei com Jquery e também não funcionou

Alguém pode me dar uma luz ?

Comment: Testei aqui com mesmo domínio e domínios diferentes e funcionou normal.

Comment: Tente alterar o `name` para `id`...

Comment: Testei aqui e funciona normalmente com o `id` ao invés de `name`.

Comment: Então ainda não funcionou, mas fiz um teste e ele não está funcionando por que estou utilizando height de tamanho fixo pra ficar sem aquela barra de rolagem no iframe ou seja. Se eu tiro heigth fixa e ponho algo como auto ou 100% ele funciona normal porém ,  o iframe fica minusculo tendo que ficar rolando caso o cara não utilize as ancoras!

Answer (score 2):

Quando você usa o `#(hash)` no `href` ele faz referência a um `id`, isto posto:

altere :

```
<a name="ancora"></a>
```

para

```
<a id="ancora"></a>
```

Comment: Então ainda não funcionou, mas fiz um teste e ele não está funcionando por que estou utilizando height de tamanho fixo pra ficar sem aquela barra de rolagem no iframe ou seja. Se eu tiro heigth fixa e ponho algo como auto ou 100% ele funciona normal porém , o iframe fica minusculo tendo que ficar rolando caso o cara não utilize as ancoras!

Comment: Tá o que exatamente vc quer fazer, a solução vc já tem...